# Dreaming of Chiranjeevis

Tags: symbolism, dream, ashwatthama, chiranjivi

Today I got a dream of a man who claimed to be there since the start of the world, he was pale with no eyes, he told me if you want to visualize a face just imagine it. The rest of the dream is just noise and nonsense, but I interestingly had deja-vu remembering getting him before when I wasn't religious. This guy instantly made me think of Ashvantama. I am wondering the significance of dreaming about Chiranjeevis and what this actually could mean.